# Override Scringo Signup, Login, and Logout Completed Events

Tags: android

I have successfully integrated Scringo into my Android app.However, I would like to do something at runtime after a successful signup, login, and logout. How do I go about this. Please help. I've searched google but to no avail. I've also contacted the Scringo team but haven't heard from them. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I work for Scringo ;-) And didn't receive your email... next time try support@scringo.com

In Android: Create a broadcast receiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.scringo.LoginBroadcast")) {
            String userId = intent.getExtras().getString("userId");
            String accountId = intent.getExtras().getString("accountId");
            ScringoLogger.e("Got receiver: " + accountId + ", " + userId);      
        }
    }
}
```

And register it in the manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.example.MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.scringo.LoginBroadcast" />
            <category android:name="com.example" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Added this: http://docs.scringo.com/android-guides/popular/handling-login-status-changes/

In iOS it's even simpler, you have the "kNotificationUserSignInChanged" defined in Scringo.h to which you should add an observer and you'll receive a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(statusChanged) name:kNotificationUserSignInChanged object:nil];
```

Hope that helps